# how to split a column in to two columns in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I am using postgresql database. I have a table called "notifications" which consists of a column called Time which has both date and time value like this
--> time
   2014-07-24 19:11:18
I want to split this time column in to time and date column.
How to do this?Someone do help me...

Comment: do u want to store the data in your datadase or u just want to display in runtime??

Answer (score 1):

if your column is of type text (or timestamp or any explicitly casted), then:

```
t=# with d as (select '2014-07-24 19:11:18'::text col) select col::date, col::time from d;
    col     |   col
------------+----------
 2014-07-24 | 19:11:18
(1 row)

Time: 0.826 ms
```

here d is your table and col is your column:

```
select col::date, col::time from d;
```